# How to build protobuf-c in windows using mingw?

Tags: c, protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

I can successfully build protobuf in Windows, it result in three .lib files, but don't know how to build protobuf-c in Windows, there are no documents about it.

Answer (score 1):

i was able to do that with Cygwin:

you can download the sources from here https://github.com/protobuf-c/protobuf-c

depending on the protobuf that you've compiled you can download the "right" version of the protobuf-c.

generally speaking, to build with Cygwin you'll need to add on top of the default installation:

1. gcc and the tools around it.
2. tools to build protobuf and protobuf-c as documented in the Github of each (https://github.com/protobuf-c/protobuf-c). build protobuf again i suspect for Cygwin to recognize it?
3. build as told (same for both):

   - ./autogen.sh
   - ./configure --prefix=/usr
   - make
   - make install